# Использование и установка breakpoint в редакторе для Scintilla

Tags: delphi, delphi-10-seattle, scintilla

Есть проект, который использует обвертку визуального редактора Scintilla https://github.com/KrystianBigaj/dscintilla и сама документация http://www.scintilla.org/ScintillaDoc. Как в Scintilla можно сделать по левому полю установку любго количество BREAKPOINTов и как потом узнать номер строки и данные, где были установленные указанные breakpoints.

Что бы по левому полю отображались номера строк использую следующий код:

```
with Scintilla do
begin
  SetScrollWidth(430); //so we don't see it
  Margins.Right:=1;
  Margins.Left:=0;
  Margins.Top:=0;
  Margins.Bottom:=0;
  SetMarginLeft(5);
  SetMarginWidthN(0,40);
  SetMarginWidthN(1,0);
  SetExtraAscent(4); //space between lines

  //-----------------------margin line numbers
  StyleSetFont(STYLE_LINENUMBER, 'Default');
  StyleSetBold(STYLE_LINENUMBER, true);
  StyleSetBack(STYLE_LINENUMBER, RGB(240,240,240));
  StyleSetFore(STYLE_LINENUMBER, clBlue);
end;
```

Использую Delphi 10 Seattle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Может кому пригодиться, данное решение.

Первое создаем базовый класс для BreakPoints:

```
unit uBreakPoint;

interface

type

  TBreakPoint = class
  private
    FLineNumber                       : Integer;
    FLineString                       : string;
  public
    property LineNumber               : Integer read FLineNumber;
    property LineString               : string read FLineString;
  public
    procedure SetLineNumber(const AValue: Integer);
    procedure SetLineString(const AValue: string);
  public
    constructor Create();
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TBreakPoint.Create;
begin
  FLineNumber := -1;
end;

destructor TBreakPoint.Destroy;
begin
  inherited;
end;

procedure TBreakPoint.SetLineNumber(const AValue: Integer);
begin
  FLineNumber := Avalue;
end;

procedure TBreakPoint.SetLineString(const AValue: string);
begin
  FLineString := AValue;
end;

end.
```

Второе создаем, класс базового управления для BreakPoints:

```
unit uListBreakPoint;

interface

uses Generics.Collections, uBreakPoint, System.SysUtils;

type

  TListBreakpoint = class
  private
    FList                             : TList<TBreakPoint>;
  public
    procedure addBreakPoint(const ABreakPoint: TBreakPoint);
    procedure removeBreakPoint(const ABreakPoint: TBreakPoint); overload;
    procedure removeBreakPoint(const ALineNumber: Integer); overload;
  public
    constructor Create();
    destructor Destroy; override;
  end;

implementation

constructor TListBreakpoint.Create;
begin
  FList := TList<TBreakPoint>.Create;
end;

destructor TListBreakpoint.Destroy;
var
  BreakPoint: TBreakPoint;
begin

  for BreakPoint in FList do
    BreakPoint.Free;

  FreeAndNil(FList);
  inherited;
end;

procedure TListBreakpoint.addBreakPoint(const ABreakPoint: TBreakPoint);
begin
  FList.Add(ABreakPoint);
end;

procedure TListBreakpoint.removeBreakPoint(const ABreakPoint: TBreakPoint);
begin
  FList.Remove(ABreakPoint);
end;

procedure TListBreakpoint.removeBreakPoint(const ALineNumber: Integer);
var
  BreakPoint: TBreakPoint;
begin
  for BreakPoint in FList do
    if BreakPoint.LineNumber = ALineNumber then
      begin
        FList.Remove(BreakPoint);
        BreakPoint.Free;
        Break;
      end;
end;

end.
```

и на конец в коде где расположен редактор **Scintilla: TDScintilla;**
пишем следующий код:

```
TFormEditor = class(TForm)
...
  Scintilla: TDScintilla;
  procedure FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
  procedure ScintillaMarginClick(ASender: TObject; AModifiers, APosition, AMargin: Integer);
...
  private 
    FListBreakpoint: TListBreakpoint;
...
end;

implementation

procedure TFormEditor.FormCreate(Sender: TObject);
begin

  FListBreakpoint := TListBreakpoint.Create;

  with Scintilla do
    begin
      // Настройка полей редактора

      // Установка поля маркера
      SetMarginTypeN(0, SC_MARGIN_SYMBOL);
      SetMarginWidthN(0, 5); // установим ширину поля
      SetMarginSensitiveN(0, True); // Установим что поле кликабельное

      // Установка числового поля
      SetMarginTypeN(1, SC_MARGIN_NUMBER);
      SetMarginWidthN(1, 50);
      SetMarginSensitiveN(1, True);

      // устанвить индексы маркеров
      // DEBUG
      MarkerDefine(0, SC_MARK_CIRCLE);
      MarkerSetBack(0, RGB(38, 127, 0));
      MarkerSetFore(0, 0);
      // ERROR
      MarkerDefine(1, SC_MARK_ARROW);
      MarkerSetBack(1, 255);
      MarkerSetFore(1, 0);
    end;

end;

procedure TFormEditor.ScintillaMarginClick(ASender: TObject;
  AModifiers, APosition, AMargin: Integer);
begin
  var
    LineFromPosition: Integer;
    MarketGet: Integer;
    BreakPoint: TBreakPoint;

begin

  LineFromPosition := Scintilla.LineFromPosition(APosition);
  MarketGet := Scintilla.MarkerGet(LineFromPosition);

  // проверим установлен маркер или нет (1-да)
  if (MarketGet = 1) or (MarketGet = 2) then
    begin
      // убрать маркер
      Scintilla.MarkerDelete(LineFromPosition, 0);
      FListBreakpoint.removeBreakPoint(LineFromPosition);
    end
      else
        begin
          // установить маркер
          Scintilla.MarkerAdd(LineFromPosition, 0);
          // Создать BreakPoint, запомнить его состяние и сохранить в списке
          BreakPoint := TBreakPoint.Create();
          BreakPoint.SetLineNumber(LineFromPosition);
          BreakPoint.SetLineString(Scintilla.GetLine(LineFromPosition));
          FListBreakpoint.addBreakPoint(BreakPoint);
        end;
end;
```

Надеюсь кому то поможет сократить время :-)